# Question on Differential Equation mixture problem involving rate in rate out1

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

A tank contains 50 gallons of a solution composed of 90% water and 10% alcohol. A second solution containing 50% water and 50% alcohol is added to the tank at the rate of 4 gallons per minute. As the second solution is being added the tank is drained at the rate of 5 gallons per minute. Assuming that the solution in the tank is stirred constantly ,determine how much alcohol is in the tank after 10minutes.

Comment: What have you attempted so far?

Comment: I tried using the homogenous differential method but along the way I got stack. Using the exact differential method made things worse. If someone has the solution maybe you can forward please

Comment: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/Modeling.aspx this might help, try and see if you could figure out the details! Otherwise I will try to write an answer later today.